# Is it possible to use the vaadin-grid inside a LitElement of a Polymer application?

Tags: polymer, web-component, vaadin-grid

What is the minimum example, if any, using the Polymer PWA (https://polymer.github.io/pwa-starter-kit/), to show correctly a vaadin-grid?
I tried many different combinations, but never a working one, with, often, this warning:
property-accessors.js:275 Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON
Am I doing anything totally wrong?
Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from the v5.2.0-beta1 we recommend using following Grid features:

- column helper elements (`vaadin-grid-filter-column`, `vaadin-grid-sort-column`)
- column convenience properties (`path`, `header` and `text-align`)
- renderers for more complex cases where you previously used templates

See the example here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lying-blanket?path=app.js:29:42
https://lying-blanket.glitch.me/

Note: I'm using `fetch` API here for simplicity only, you can use XHR if necessary.

Comment: Is there anything like a "vaadin-grid-filter-sort-column" to use filter _AND_ sort in a column? Thanks.